# modifying excel cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a value CFC3042A in a cell and need to convert it to show 2a04c3cf. I can split the left and right two numbers and reverse them but can not extract the second and third pair of characters

Comment: Please include your attempt, you might not be far off. Also, would that always be the same pattern, of has it got to be in pairs of two with a variable total lenght but a multiple of two? Also, is the lower case lettern on purpose? I suggest to update your question with some more relevant information. It might be relevant to also let us know what version of Excel you are using for this.

Comment: Refer ... https://exceljet.net/formula/reverse-text-string ..... and you can just mention the position in the formula as you want

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you an example with [`CONCAT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function:

---

*Assuming:*

- your strings are 8 characters long
- you still need characters to be upper-case

  ```
  =CONCAT(MID(A1,{7,5,3,1},2))
  ```

---

*In case you got a string with:*

- a variable length but;
- a total length that is a multiple of 2

  ```
  =CONCAT(MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)/2))*2),2))
  ```

  - The idea is to feed `MID` the exact same array of numbers as above > `{7,5,3,1}`
  - `LEN(A1)+1-ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)/2))*2)` - This is where we get the initial array of numbers from. Math will get us `8+1-({1,2,3,4}*2)` > `9-{2,4,6,8}`. The resulting array is what we were after.

---

**Note1:** The second option is an array formula and needs to be confirmerd through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note2:** Include a `LOWER` function at the front if you must turn this into lower-case letters.